# Multivariate Q-Q plot to compare datasets

Tags: data-visualization, computational-statistics, qq-plot

I'm trying to compare two datasets, each of two dimensions with unequal size. I tried using Q-Q plot to compare the datasets however I find it's implementation quite difficult. Can anyone suggest some alternative approaches to compare the two datasets.

Comment: I think you should consider DD plots (bi-variate extention of the QQ plot) for comparing two distributions. Have a look at this (long) discussion paper:    "Multivariate analysis by data depth: descriptive statistics, graphics and inference, (with discussion and a rejoinder by Liu and Singh)"
R. Y. Liu, J. M. Parelius, and K. Singh.  Ann. Statist.   Volume 27. 1999, 783-858.